# Every change reload iOS simulator

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Nativescript reloads application in iOS simulator whenever I edit any `*.ts` file.

Can I modify files without reloading simulator? Like ReactNative hotswap? When it reloads only `jsbundle` without reloading an app.

Comment: break the running execution script by ctrl+c then make changes and when you want to reload. run the `tns run` command

Comment: Can't I use `tns debug` and hot swap together?

Comment: if you don't break `tns debug` or `tns run` running script then any changes in TS will immediately reflect in emulator by reloading.